# Search for sharp maximums of 4D surface

Tags: optimization, surfaces

I need to find **sharp** local maximums of numerically defined 4D surface.

I have a surface with lots of maximums. **I already know how to find them all.** Some of them look like this: [wide extremum](http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/20/fjodorych.0/0_a869_3b67bf35_orig), others more like this [sharp peak](http://paulholding.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Laila-Peak-Camp.jpg). **I need to find only sharp ones.**

For now I'm calculating ratio of peak height to it's volume (calculated by numerical integration). Unfortunately I was not able to find any suitable ratio threshold. Any threshold *suits* only for small part of surface. What else features of peaks may be useful to research?

For now *suitableness* of maximums is detected manually - I'm developing some computer vision software.

Does my problem have a specific name and methods? How it should be solved? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're finding maxima (or minima) of some function then you are in the business of "**optimization**". There is a vast amount of software available to help with this. The best algorithm for your situation will depend on the nature of your problem. A good place to start looking for software is [the NEOS site](http://neos-server.org/neos/).

The sharpness of a peak can be judged by estimating the radius of curvature at the maximum point. If you have a way to calculate function derivatives, you can calculate curvature analytically; if not, use a finite-difference approximation.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't formulated the question clearly - I already know how to find extremums of my surface (just fixed the question to clear that out), so optimisation is already done (I'm using some kind of simplex method). Now I need to find "sharp" maximums among all.

Comment: Sorry. I thought you were saying that the needed estimates must be sharp (i.e. accurate). I added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Curvature is a new term for me. And it looks just like the figure I need.